# How can i overcome the Connection refused problem in my serever

Tags: php, json, api, curl, soap

I wrote a curl code to run a SMS API. It worked well in localhost. When I uploaded it into the webhosting it showed error like ***Failed to connect to smeapps.mobitel.lk port 8585: Connection refused***.

I don't know how can I solve it??

Here is the code which I wrote.

```php
<?php
// Your ID and token

//Content-Type: application/json
 //Accept: application/json
//header('Content-Type: application/json');
//header('Accept: application/json');

$blogID = 'xxxxxx';
$authToken = 'xxxxx';

// The data to send to the API
$postData = array(
    'username' => 'xxxxx',
    'password' => 'xxxx',
    'from' => 'xxxx',
    'to' => '07612xxxxx',
    'text'=>'hello',
    'messageType'=>0
);





// Setup cURL
$ch = curl_init('http://smeapps.mobitel.lk:8585/EnterpriseSMSV3/esmsproxyURL.php');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Authorization: '.$authToken,
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Accept: application/json'
    ),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postData)
));

// Send the request
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Check for errors
if($response === FALSE){
    die(curl_error($ch));
}

// Decode the response
$responseData = json_decode($response, TRUE);

// Print the date from the response
//echo $responseData['published'];

?>
```

The link is also mentioned in the code. Can anyone help me to resolve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should ask your web hosting provider support. They'll be able to debug this problem much better than we can.

Comment: Can be your local firewall blocking that port or the host you want to connect. Maybe your IP needs to be whitelisted. Also you may need to use https instead?

Comment: thank you for your response @  Bartosz Zasada. i was already spoke with them. but they said their side didn't shown any issues..is that any API stored server restriction???

Comment: thank you for your response @  Markus Zeller. earlier when i was detect the problem i spoke with them and check with them like is that API blacklisted or not??....they said that API didn't blacklisted in my hosting... is there any alternative solutions there....